# Why isn't valid geometry not valid in NetTopologySuite when close to poles?

Tags: openlayers-2, c#, coordinate-system, nettopologysuite

I have a Polygon which crosses the south pole:

## Polygon in WKT:

```
POLYGON((5.86826073458095 75.6638564054071,-16.5436836399021 63.2220742891438,-19.3664667294083 59.846221066959,-21.7009816876343 56.4249469806136,-23.6790769742369 52.9700261291777,-25.3903613659649 49.4893115487179,-26.8975641104604 45.9882370271908,-28.2457890135821 42.4706937235238,-29.4682588331783 38.9395620194517,-30.5899861803996 35.3970453090933,-31.630184235186 31.8448854932665,-32.6038903163747 28.2845058942699,-33.5230853693438 24.7171076354231,-34.3974830618665 21.1437357309945,-35.235097920163 17.5653249360032,-36.0426631616959 13.9827314320988,-36.8259448200183 10.3967548983886,-37.5899837597522 6.80815365993192,-38.3392875692471 3.21765455357868,-39.0779879379052 -0.374040045499291,-39.8099755194243 -3.96624846033375,-40.5390214169723 -7.55830680566397,-41.2688934869779 -11.1495673752539,-42.0034749866572 -14.7393968944145,-42.746893755425 -18.3271748440658,-43.5036712696367 -21.9122899273912,-44.278903931454 -25.4941353358308,-45.0784929992426 -29.0721003174899,-45.909447175354 -32.645558114512,-46.780293059812 -36.213846909671,-47.701647966567 -39.7762416028947,-48.6870411529217 -43.3319115133841,-49.7541238657166 -46.8798560026433,-50.9265051564415 -50.4188052017007,-52.2366277028469 -53.9470627335416,-53.7304380696443 -57.4622479660316,-55.4752902472004 -60.960856256507,-57.5739735146974 -64.4374691598322,-60.1910293117637 -67.8832485002322,-63.6053872681201 -71.2828461995608,-68.3234045243048 -74.6074769312702,-75.3289981196023 -77.7943686089884,-86.6900534465662 -80.7085557183446,-106.466508019701 -83.0072017934104,-137.471660384609 -83.9399343949619,-168.142998855139 -82.93831462336,172.499462776297 -80.6056412046207,51.3335176218797 -89.5237677724837,-38.5840495672926 -86.5116366536384,-42.0040683719443 -83.0274485267546,-42.8274013155417 -79.5453266210156,-43.0035444063044 -76.0523116952844,-42.917334253526 -72.5396798562258,-42.697949818896 -69.0250062191839,-42.4008670872053 -65.5077449057289,-42.0533899183215 -61.9874560043951,-41.670338636158 -58.4637908672109,-41.2602920462013 -54.9364821865153,-40.8284114298265 -51.4053395233125,-40.3778451376451 -47.870247975915,-39.910479310127 -44.3311678973098,-39.4273617133736 -40.7881352756541,-38.9289507663875 -37.2412619762738,-38.4152654790081 -33.6907357058719,-37.8859761502671 -30.1368196717061,-37.3404576571625 -26.5798516624587,-36.7778177194076 -23.0202428850507,-36.1969072178556 -19.4584768387702,-35.5963164344505 -15.8951075671059,-34.9743593186678 -12.3307588680448,-34.3290462758966 -8.76612330851596,-33.6580452149769 -5.20196287319082,-32.9586293654512 -1.63911024976531,-32.2276096954905 1.92152745183098,-31.4612484461671 5.47896267724487,-30.6551491136678 9.03211742916007,-29.8041161495169 12.5798092697371,-28.9019756079644 16.120730246266,-27.9413441489322 19.6534181565979,-26.9133294556999 23.1762163144254,-25.8071382075058 26.6872181913455,-24.6095580924228 30.1841914502993,-23.3042664371652 33.6644728848271,-21.8708974452426 37.1248226005016,-20.2837701533619 40.5612194847865,-18.5101356399938 43.9685706157486,-16.50773911296 47.3402932700171,-14.2214065316975 50.6677038885502,-11.5782579077352 53.9391116046634,-8.48105249750914 57.1384547629944,-4.79920779006745 60.2432297260212,-0.357592488403802 63.2213436295558,5.07464609178979 66.0264264522405,5.86826073458095 75.6638564054071))
```

## Problem:

When I view it on google earth, it looks and acts fine. But when I try to do an intersecttion with [NetTopologySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/) (a C# library) it gives me an error basically saying it's an invalid polygon.

```c#
geom = (Geometry)swathGeom.Intersection((IGeometry)_WESTERN_HEMISPHERE);
```

## Error:

> "found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING(-86.6900534465662
>   -80.7085557183446, -106.466508019701 -83.0072017934104) and LINESTRING(-168.142998855139 -82.93831462336, 0 -81.7868941512966) [
>   (-101.975528861504, -82.4852087548192, NaN) ]"

## Question:

How can I get NetTopologySuite to see this as a valid polygon so I can perform an intersection? Do I need to do something with projection?

## Polygon in Google Earth:

[image]
[image]

## Polygon in OpenLayers:

[image]

Comment: I got the same problem with the following code. GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory(); var x = new[] { new Coordinate(163.546005249023, 193.466995239258), new Coordinate(178.168801206996, 192.997662542249), new Coordinate(181.632496051617, 194.452159296111), new Coordinate(178.641017490741, 196.724558645581), new Coordinate(167.733001708984, 199.367004394531), new Coordinate(163.546005249023, 193.466995239258) };
var pol1 = gf.CreatePolygon(x); var y = new[] { new Coordinate(136.283004760742, 126.388999938965), new Coordinate(152.889125176513, 119.454734593318), new Coordinate(202.9814572

Answer (score 1):

I've checked a little bit and I can confirm that your polygon isn't valid "as is".
This unit test is ok.

```
WKTReader reader = new KTReader(GeometryFactory.Default);  
IGeometry g = reader.Read(geomwkt);  
Assert.IsNotNull(g);  
Assert.IsFalse(g.IsValid);  
g = g.Buffer(0);  
Assert.IsTrue(g.IsValid);
```

Comment: Therein lies the problem. It IS a valid polygon on the surface of the earth, but since it crosses directly over the south pole, it freaks. It has 2 points in that polygon that all of a sudden are on opposite sides of the grid and when it plots those points they intersect each other. My guess is that NetTopologySuite and OpenLayers are 2D api's and can't handle the 3D component. But I'm not sure.

Comment: NetTopologySuite is a 2D API and don't handle properly 3D component, this is for sure. http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/jts-faq/jts-faq.html#B

Comment: !D_Buidi: Do you know of any 3D API's which I can do intersections with?

Comment: Actually... If my polygon runs around the globe several times, Is that what constitutes it needing 3D or simply having a Z value?

Comment: @CaptDragon actually, no :(
AFAIK MsSQL topology functions handle geography objects, that actually looks what you need

Comment: I see...so while NetTopologySuite handles 2-dimensional linear geometry, It does not do well with geography. So I should use something like MSSQL functions. Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of geometry is _WESTERN_HEMISPHERE? I can try to check if some bugs exists.
Anyway, you can make a valid geometry from a geometry symply calling mygeom.Buffer(0).

Comment: `Geometry _WESTERN_HEMISPHERE = (Geometry)_wktReader.Read("POLYGON((0 90, -180 90, -180 -90, 0 -90, 0 90))");`